# Spring entity dynamically calculated field with parameter from native query

Tags: spring, hibernate, jdbc

I have a somewhat complex entity like following (Notice the super-class with many more fields):

```
public class Question extends Entry {

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "question")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Answer> answers = new ArrayList<>();

    private Long viewCount = 0L;

    private Category category;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<QuestionTranslation> translations = new ArrayList<>();

    @Transient
    private double distance;
}
```

`distance` should be calculated from the DB when retrieving the result set from a native query.
E.g.

```
SELECT q.*, ST_Distance_Sphere(cast(q.location as geometry), ST_MakePoint(cast(?1 as double precision), cast(?2 as double precision))) as distance from question q
```

I cannot use `@Formula` to annotate my field `distance` since the query has to take parameters.

How can I map the field `distance` from the SQL query result to my entity field `distance` while leaving all the other mappings to be done by Hibernate?

#### Edit

Based on @gmotux suggestion I created a wrapper entity.

```
@Entity
@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name="MappingQ",
        entities={
                @EntityResult(
                        entityClass = QuestionWithDistance.class,
                        fields={
                                @FieldResult(name="distance",column="distance"),
                                @FieldResult(name="question",column="question")})})
public class QuestionWithDistance{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private String id;

    @OneToOne
    private Question question;
    private double distance;
}
```

Query

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT q.*, 222.22 as distance from question q", "MappingQ");
```

But it always fails with

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name id1_15_0_ was not found in this ResultSet.
```

Comment: Hello @isADon, I have the same issue (using MySQL instead). Were you able to find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you need extra parameters to calculate your field, you indeed cannot use @Formula, or even a getter to calculate the field.
Unfortunately for your case the only thing that comes to mind, assuming you are using an EntityManager based configuration for Hibernate, is leveraging its @PostLoad event listener, which you can use for calculating field values upon entity loading, like :

```
public class Question extends Entry {
    @PostLoad
    private void postLoad() {
        this.distance = DistanceCalculator.calculateDistance(Double param1,Double param2);       
        //other calculations
    }
}
```

That of-course is only a workaround and it means that you must have a static method somewhere execute native queries. 
I would suggest detaching the "distance" notion from your Question entity, if possible in your requirements and calculate it, when required, with either a native SQL function call or a service method.

Comment: When retrieving the result set from the SQL query I already sort the list by distance using the PostGIS function call. Meaning the distance for each element is already calculated from the DB. I really would like to find a way to not have my Spring Application do the calculation again and instead get the value straight from the DB.

Comment: If i understand correctly, the problem is that you need a field that is only transient during persistence. In a similar situation i made an envelope and custom mapped my query to that envelope (i.e. separate your distance field from the question entity and wrap them in a custom entity class with 2 fields : a Question and a non-transient "distance" field). Afterwards you can use SqlResultSetMapping to map your query to that wrapper. You would then be able to persist your Question entities separately.

Comment: Please see my edit. Did I understand your suggestion correctly?